# How to reset synch with a database on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a lot of issues with rails migration mechanism.
I think I have run a migration file and has been executed partially. 
So when I am trying to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

again it gives me an error the column name already exist. 
I am trying to reset it with

```
rake db:reset
```

and gives me an error

```
Unknown database 'databasename'
```

Is there a way to reset the whole mechanism ?
Is it a good idea to manually drop all tables and try to run rake db:migrate again ?

Comment: What about `rake db:drop`? Does it work?

Comment: No it gives me "Unknown database databaseName"

Answer (score 0):

You should change the database name in your database.yml.

Comment: Look through your sourcecode if you find somewhere an accidentially written "databasename".